# How do I fix the syntax in my code to make my radio buttons work with my dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, radio-button, tkinter

I am trying to learn how to use a *dictionary* with a radio button. I have the code below but when ever I run it I get an error.
The error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Volumes/CHROME
USB/STORAGE/TKinker GUI/Radiobutton + Dictionary.py", line 16, in
<module>
    for i in sorted(choices.keys()): NameError: name 'choices' is not defined
```

Here's my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        w = Label(master, text="1. Anxiety, nervousness, worry or fear")
        w.pack()

    choices = {
    1: "not at all",
    2: "somewhat",
    3: "moderately",
    4: "a lot"
    }

for i in sorted(choices.keys()):
    label = "%s - %s" % (i, choices[i])
    rb=Radiobutton(master, text=label, variable=v, value=i)
    rb.pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")

    choices = {
    1: "not at all",
    2: "somewhat",
    3: "moderately",
    4: "a lot"
    }

    v = IntVar()
    Radiobutton(master, text="0 for not at all", variable=v, value=1).pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")
    Radiobutton(master, text="1 for somewhat", variable=v, value=2).pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")
    Radiobutton(master, text="2 for moderatly", variable=v, value=3).pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")
    Radiobutton(master, text="3 for a lot", variable=v, value=4).pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")

    self.button = Button(master, text="BACK", fg="red", command=self.button6)
    self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    self.button = Button(master, text="NEXT", fg="red", command=self.button5)
    self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    def button6(self):
        print "Sam is awesome!GAJONGA" 

    def button5(self):
        print "PYTHON FOR THE WIN! GIAN SAYS PYTHON = FILTHY" 

master = Tk()
app = App(master)
master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided the crucial info -- what line the error happens on.

However, you appear to have an indentation error here:

```
for i in sorted(choices.keys()):
    label = "%s - %s" % (i, choices[i])
    rb=Radiobutton(master, text=label, variable=v, value=i)
    rb.pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")
```

The lines inside the `for` loop need to be indented.

If fixing that doesn't fix your problem please leave a comment on my answer and update your question with the line number and the code with the indentation fixed.

---

Updated answer for the updated question:

Try this code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        w = Label(master, text="1. Anxiety, nervousness, worry or fear")
        w.pack()

        choices = {
        1: "not at all",
        2: "somewhat",
        3: "moderately",
        4: "a lot"
        }

        for i in sorted(choices.keys()):
            v = IntVar()
            label = "%s - %s" % (i, choices[i])
            rb=Radiobutton(master, text=label, variable=v, value=i)
            rb.pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")

        self.button = Button(master, text="BACK", fg="red", command=self.button6)
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.button = Button(master, text="NEXT", fg="red", command=self.button5)
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    def button6(self):
        print "Sam is awesome!GAJONGA"

    def button5(self):
        print "PYTHON FOR THE WIN! GIAN SAYS PYTHON = FILTHY"

master = Tk()
app = App(master)
master.mainloop()
```

That appears to be what you're trying to do. Observe the indentation closely and also where I moved the `v = IntVar()` line.

Comment: " for (i in sorted(choices.keys())):" in this line the ":" at the end is causing the problem.

Comment: Fix the indentation. Also, I don't know if the out parenthesis are a problem or not, but they're definitely not necessary: `for i in sorted(choices.keys()):` would be correct. See my edited answer.

Comment: I edited my question with the new code and the new error. Thank your for helping :-)

Comment: I added fixed code to my answer. Please click the check mark next to it to accept if it helped you.